# How can I update the photo within a button using radio buttons?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm currently trying to learn how to build GUIs with tkinter, and I've run into a problem with my test app.

I have a button that displays an image on it instead of text, and I also have a set of radio buttons that I want to control which image is shown on the regular button. Currently the radio buttons don't seem to be updating my `photofilepath` StringVar as the button always has the default photo, regardless of selected radio button. Here is my (Simplified) code:

```
root = Tk()  # Set up 
root.title("Test GUI")
gui.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

photofilepath = StringVar()  # Set default photo
photofilepath.set("C:/Users/Ben/Pictures/Default photo.png")
photo = PhotoImage(file=photofilepath.get())

CalcButton = ttk.Button(gui, image=photo)
CalcButton.grid(column=3, row=2, columnspan=1)

# Set button photo
Photo1Rbutton = ttk.Radiobutton(gui, text="Photo 1", variable=photofilepath,
                                  value='C:/Users/Ben/Pictures/Photo 1.png')
Photo1Rbutton.grid(column=4, row=2, sticky=S)
Photo2Rbutton = ttk.Radiobutton(gui, text="Photo 2", variable=photofilepath,
                                  value='C:/Users/Ben/Pictures/Photo 2.png')
Photo2Rbutton.grid(column=4, row=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: radiobutton will not execute (automatically) `PhotoImage(...)` to load new image, and `CalcButton[image] = photo` to replace image on button.

Comment: Thanks @furas You helped me on my previous question aswell.

Comment: I'm creating full working example because your example doesn't work ;) For example you have unknown variable `gui` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `command=` in `Radiobutton` to assign function which will load new image and put them in label.

Working example (you have to only set paths)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# to easily change example
DEFAULT = "C:/Users/Ben/Pictures/Default photo.png"
PHOTO_1 = "C:/Users/Ben/Pictures/Photo 1.png"
PHOTO_2 = "C:/Users/Ben/Pictures/Photo 2.png"


def change_image():
    print(photo_filepath.get())

    photo = tk.PhotoImage(file=photo_filepath.get())
    calc_button['image'] = photo
    calc_button.image = photo # solution for garbage-collector problem. you have to assign PhotoImage object to global variable or class variable

    # - or -

    photo['file'] = photo_filepath.get()
    calc_button['image'] = photo


root = tk.Tk()  # Set up 
root.title("Test GUI")

photo_filepath = tk.StringVar()  # Set default photo
photo_filepath.set(DEFAULT)

photo = tk.PhotoImage(file=photo_filepath.get())

calc_button = ttk.Button(root, image=photo)
calc_button.grid(column=3, row=2, columnspan=1)

photo1_radiobutton = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Photo 1", variable=photo_filepath,
                                  value=PHOTO_1, command=change_image)
photo1_radiobutton.grid(column=4, row=2, sticky=tk.S)

photo2_radiobutton = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Photo 2", variable=photo_filepath,
                                  value=PHOTO_2, command=change_image)
photo2_radiobutton.grid(column=4, row=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this doesn't actually seem to work for me, the image does swap, but it swaps to a transparent/blank image, leaving me with a default button. Only the default image seems to work.

Comment: did you tried `photo['file'] = photo_filepath.get()` . I forgot that `PhotoImage` may have problem with garbage-collector when it is used in function and assigned to local variable. Garbage-collector removes image but it should't. I changed code.

Comment: see Note at the end of page http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm